# Motorola SB6141 assigns 192.168.100.0/24 IP via DHCP when cable dies; can I prohibit systemd-networkd from using 192.168.100.0/24 addresses?

Tags: dhcp, systemd

I have a Motorola SB6141 cable modem connected to a Linux firewall that obtains an IP via systemd-networkd's DHCP function.  Every so often, the ISP will have issues, and for some reason, systemd-networkd gets assigned an IP in the 192.168.100.0/24 range (instead of one of the ISP's public IP addresses).  When this happens, the 192.168.100.0/24 IP address "sticks" and I have to restart the systemd-networkd service, to which it then gets the real public IP address.

I have two ways I can fix this:

- Prohibit the Motorola SB6141 modem from handing out 192.168.100.0/24 IPs.
- Prohibit networkd-systemd from accepting IPs in the 192.168.100.0/24 range.

However, I don't know how to do either of these things (if they are possible).  What should I do from here?

Comment: Get static IP addresses. You are using business-class service, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a cron job which checks the IP Address, and restarts systemd-networkd if it has one in the 192.168.100.0/24 range